# Android Support Repository, SDK Patch Applier v4 and 4 more SDK components were not installed

Tags: java, android

Android Support Repository, SDK Patch Applier v4 and 4 more SDK components were not installed...

[image]

Comment: try to install it from sdk and skip this step.

Comment: I "installed" your image inline your question... Maybe it will help. If you have any other usefull info to add to your question, feel free to edit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

just click on cancel and when you are done with setup, you can update and install it later.

from [official android site](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html):

To open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager  in the toolbar. If you're not using Android Studio, you can download tools using the sdkmanager command-line tool.

When an update is available for a package you already have, a dash  appears in the check box next to the package.

To update an item or install a new one, click the check box so it shows a checkmark.
To uninstall a package, click to clear the check box.
Pending updates are indicated in the left column with a download icon . Pending removals are indicated with a red cross .

To update the selected packages, click Apply or OK, then agree to any license agreements.

[image]

Comment: A new Android Studio 2.2.3 is available in the stable channel. 
This message appears with an updated version, and when I press the "Update and Restart"
>>> Failed to download patch files

Comment: in downloading component click on `Show Details` to see what's the problem